# How to resolve this absolute value inequality $|1+x^2|>|x|$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am stuck trying to find all x that satisfies

$$|1+x^2|>|x|$$

($x=0$ is obvious.)

To provide more context, I had applied the root test on the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{n^2 + x^{2n}} $$

and set the limit < 1, to force convergence.

The n's conveniently converged, leaving me with only the inequality left above, involving only x.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: If $x\ge 0$, then you have $1+x^2 > x$. If $x<0$ you have $1+x^2 >-x$. Or, you could argue: If $0 < x< 1$, then the LHS is bigger than $1$, bigger than the RHS. If $x> 1$, then $x^2 > x$, so the LHS is bigger than the RHS. If $x$ is negative, the same cases with a minus sign should yield that it holds for all $x$.

Comment: since both sides are nonnegative, you can square both sides to get an equivalent inequality

Comment: Both functions in the equality are even, so it suffices to show that the identity holds for $x \geq 0$, in which case it simplifies to $1 + x^2 > x$. But this is equivalent to $x^2 - x + 1 > 0$, and the l.h.s. is $(x - \tfrac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{4},$ which is a sum of a nonnegative quantity and positive quantity.

Comment: The inequality of the post is more or less irrelevant for the issue of convergence that motivated it.

Comment: Hi @AndréNicolas, yes, I know that there's a very quick solution to it:  dividing top and bottom by the numerator and checking the behavior of the denominator.  But I wouldn't have been able to spot that myself, so I went to the route that would be most natural: applying the root test and setting it  <1.  Can I ask you a quick question?

Comment: As  you see, many on here are answering that *all x* satisfies the inequality, but in fact, the series diverges like the harmonic series at x=1.  ... why didn't the root test "catch" that?  It's not like I set the limit =1, so the inconclusive case...shouldn't happen, if that makes any sense.  @AndreNicolas - thanks,

Comment: The answers about the inequality are all correct. Somewhere earlier in your calculation there is a mistake. I would not use the Root Test, looking at the sum is better.

Comment: Hi @AndréNicolas, do you mind elaborating how to look at the sum?  I have tried for a bit, but can't seem to be precise.  I first did this:  the sum diverges at x=1.  Now I consider two other cases:  for x<1 the sum is approximately $\large \sum \frac{x^n}{n}$, which converges like the geometric series.  The third case, for x>1, the sum is approximately like $\large \sum \frac{n}{x^n}$, but I'm not sure how to claim that this series converges.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Ooh, and I caught my computational mistake in using the root test @AndréNicolas...was moving too fast and treated the denominator as a product, and distributed the 1/nth-root...

Comment: If $x\gt 1$, then $\sum \frac{n}{x^n}$ converges by the Ratio Test, or the Root Test. By the way, one can be more precise than saying "approximately", use explicit inequalities, And you have forgotten about the negative part of the world. The arguments for $x$ negative with absolute value $\lt 1$, $\gt 1$ will be like those for positive $x$. The situation when $x=-1$ will be different, we get convergence (alternating series).

Comment: Hi @AndréNicolas, sorry, I am having some trouble with the case for x<1.  For x =1, we get divergence.  For x>1, the summands are positive and we can compare the series to a larger one like the one you mention, and we show the convergence of the larger series by either the Ratio or Root test.  But...we can't use comparison tests, when x is negative...so how can I proceed?  Thanks,

Comment: You say $x\lt 1$, but there are really four cases that have $x\lt 1$. We can have $0\le x\lt 1$, $-1\lt x\lt 0$, $x=-1$, and $x\lt -1$. Some of these can be handled together. For example $-1\lt x\lt 1$ can be handled by taking absolute values. For recall that if $\sum |a_n|$ converges then so does $\sum a_n$.

Comment: ...that was much more work than anticipated.  I have worked out all 4 cases and see what you mean now.  I think case 4, $x<-1$, we get convergence from the same argument as the case for $x>1$, since as you reminded me:  the absolute convergence of a series implies the convergence of the original series.  Thanks so much for your help, @AndréNicolas.  I have been struggling with these types of series convergence problems, finding the range of $x$ correctly, so this was awesome practice.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: You are welcome. We can deal with $|x|\lt 1$ in blow, $|x|\gt 1$ in one blow, leaving the cases $-1$ (convergence, but not absolute convergence) and $1 (divergence).  Not so bad! With power series, things are typically less complicated, but this is not a power series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One may write
$$
|1+x^2|>|x|
$$ 
$$
|x|^2+1>|x|
$$ 
$$
|x|^2-|x|+1>0
$$$$
\left(|x|-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34>0
$$ thus **all real values** $x$ satisfy the initial inequation.

---

> Concerning the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{n^2 + x^{2n}}$ one may consider the following cases.
>
> - Assume $|x|<1$.
>
>   Then, we have $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{n^2 + x^{2n}}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left| \frac{nx^n}{n^2 + x^{2n}}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n|x|^n=\frac{|x|}{(1-|x|)^2}<\infty,$$ the initial series **converges absolutely** thus **converges**.
> - Assume $|x|>1$.
>
>   Then, we have $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{n^2 + x^{2n}}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left| \frac{nx^n}{n^2 + x^{2n}}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{|x|^n}=\frac{|x|}{(1-|x|)^2}<\infty,$$ the initial series **converges absolutely** thus **converges**.
> - Assume $x=1$.
>
>   Then, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{n^2 + x^{2n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^2 +1},$$ and as $n \to \infty$, $$\frac{n}{n^2 +1}\sim\frac1{n},$$ the initial series **diverges**.
> - Assume $x=-1$.
>
>   Then, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{n^2 + x^{2n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^2 +1}(-1)^n,$$ the initial series **converges conditionally** by the **alternating test**.

Comment: Interesting solution, @OlivierOloa.  But I want to point out one thing:  the series doesn't seem to converge for x =1, since the series should diverge like the harmonic series.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: and if I'm correct...then I wonder why...the root test failed to catch that scenario..@OlivierOloa ...

Comment: @User001 You are right: the series does not converge for $x=1$ since the general term behaves, when $n \to \infty$, as $\dfrac{n}{n^2+1}\sim \dfrac1n$.

Comment: Yea...I must use the ratio and root tests with some caution, when finding the ranges of x that give convergence...and sometimes I have seen that these tests, forcing convergence by setting the limit < 1 ... also has the effect of not finding *all* x for which the series converge....thanks so much @OlivierOloa,

Comment: ...so that the tests are only a "guarantee" of convergence...but it doesn't always help find all x...or exclude the necessary x values...

Comment: @User001 The test does not provide information at endpoints of the interval of convergence.

Comment: Ahhh, ok got it.  Thanks again @OlivierOloa!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Note that for all real $x$, $x^2 \ge 0$, hence $1 + x^2 > 0$, and by the AM-GM inequality, $$|1+x^2| = 1+x^2 \ge 2\sqrt{1 \cdot x^2} = 2 |x| \ge |x|.$$

Comment: Ahh...I <3 the AM-GM inequality.  Thanks for sharing @heropup!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see this is to note if $|x| \le 1$ then $|1 + x^2| \ge 1 \ge |x|$, and if $|x| \ge 1$ then $|1 + x^2| > |x^2| \ge |x|$.

Answer (score 1):

You can square both terms of the inequality and obtain $$1+2x^2+x^4>x^2$$

This is equivalent to $x^4+x^2+1>0$ which is true for every $x^2$, thus also for all $x$.

You can also see a more empirical approach by consider two cases. When $x$ has absolute value less than 1 the left hand side term is at least 1 as $x^2$ is positive, therefore the term in the modulus is bigger than 1 which is bigger than $x$.

For $x$ bigger in absolute value than 1, the square of it is positive and exceeds $|x|$, so the inequality holds as well. For example: $1.1^2=1.21>1.1$ :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\forall x :1+x^2$ is positive, |$1+x^2$| = $1+x^2$.

We only need to solve this inequality:

$1+x^2$ > $x$

$x^2-x+1$ has no roots and is positive for every $x$, this means that every $x$ satisfies the inequality.